# How to hide a user control and remove it's space

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, user-controls

I want to hide the user control in asp.net, and remove it's space .. how ?

Comment: have you tried using [Browsable(false)]. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615791/how-do-i-hide-some-of-the-default-control-properties-at-design-time-c

Comment: do you wanna render it to the page markup or not?

Answer (score 6):

```
yourUserControl.Visible=false;
```

this won't render your user control

Answer (score 4):

If you need to make that control visible later from javascript, than in your server side code, you can hide it using:

```
YourControl.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

but if you don't need to make it visible from javascript than simply set its Visible property to false.

If you use the first option than control is rendered but not shown and doesn't take any space but if you use second option, the control isn't rendered and hence can't be shown using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail, I would say there are two options:

1) add a style attribute with style="display:none"

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="MyTextBox" style="display:none" />
```

This option allows the textbox to exist on the page without being visible or taking space.

2) set visible="false"

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="MyTextBox" visible="false" />
```

This option prevents it from being rendered to the page.  Depending on the control this can have a number of other side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

set style="display:none" of the element that contain your user control.

Comment: Please explain why your answer is different to other answers?

Comment: @JRC i answered at 9:48 means  before everyone else, so tou shoud ask this questions to other answerers not me.  i think this is rude and unfair to downvote my answer :(