# Dynamically filter datagridview rows based a collection of filter terms while not engaging another sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, filter, sqlcommand

A GridView shows up as a table the moment my page loads, doing the sql query and binding it. This shows all the records.

I want to add a DropDownList that controls the conditional filtering so that different departments can choose their department (after load) and see only records for their department. But I am having trouble in finding how to make the filtered version show.

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911770/how-to-hide-a-user-control-and-remove-its-space)

The above question seems to be the closest to what I'm trying to do and I tried the chosen answer (62 votes) but I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

I have tried this:

```
DataTable d = (GridView1.DataSource as DataTable);
        d.DefaultView.RowFilter = "STATE = 'AZ'";

        GridView1.DataSource = d;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

and this:

```
(GridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("STATE = '{0}'", "AZ");
```

and other variations but no cigar. Again what I want is when I change the state to AZ the html table associated with the gridview immediately changes.  And I would like to not have to hit the db because it loaded all the states the first time. And it would be nice if I can change it back to all states and get all states again.

Comment: I'd use jquery to filter

Comment: javascript is my last resort if I can't find an answer to this @Kiryl. I just thought this way would take 3-10 lines of code versus 50 or whatever. plus I have an <asp:Button> that delivers an excel sheet based on the gridview so I didnt want that to break either.