# How to create a custom scrollable user control without BackgroundImage property in VB.NET for WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I wish to create a custom user control that does not contain BackgroundImage property.

I understand that you can not (apparently no working solution anyway) create a control that inherits another control and then remove public properties, however, I have the following code

```
Public Class Board

End Class
```

Which even though I am not "inheriting" any other controls, still has a tonne of properties I do not wish to have. I was able to create a 100% custom control using Visual Basic 6, which did not include any properties I did not want included.

How can I achieve the same objective in VB.NET 2012 (without resorting to using VB6 or "dated" code as such)

I have seen controls designed that do not have this property, so I can only assume that it IS possible -- just there is no documentation on the subject, and any subject that is parallel to this is hazy or non-functional.

Comment: what kinds of props do you see?  Since Control already has BackGroundImage, you might have to start with Component.

Comment: Why don't you override the property, set it to read only and make the EditorBrowsableState.Never

Comment: It won't show in the properties window, but intellesence will see it in code if your using it...sucks but that's what you get when you inherit another control.

Comment: Mr.CoD -- I have already looked into those examples.  The simple fact about the "EditorBrowsableState", etc, is that they are unavailable -- especially in the context of  [blah(bool)] function ()  ....

Comment: @Plutonix - not sure what you mean.  I see a whole lot of properties, and I created the UserControl as it's own project as a WinForms UserControl project type.

Comment: sorry, missed the UserControl part.  All those are part of inheriting from UserControl.  Inherit from `Label` and you'll see different ones (but no Background Image)

Comment: Functions...you said properties...

Comment: And yes you still can access them, they 're just not available in the property list...

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what is going on here >>  "Base class 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' specified for class 'Board' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' of one of its other partial types." <<  UserControls can not "inherit".  This is a UserControl, not a component, or class or any other type of which, this message happens when you try to Inherit another class, and in this error exactly, I am showing what happens if you try to Inherit the Label control.  The problem is that "UserControl" contains properties which I wish to hide

Comment: The examples here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615791/how-do-i-hide-some-of-the-default-control-properties-at-design-time-c  <<  do not work in VB.NET

Comment: Then hide them, I said you can use the browser state...

Comment: You can't remove the default ones...

Comment: if you are working in/from a UserControl project (that term has different meanings to diff people), then your class already inherits from something: UserControl, and cannot inherit from something else.  You can effectively hide properties from the prop window and then ignore them otherwise (this is what MS does with the Key events in a PicBox - they are defined as part of Control, PicBox just doesnt implement them).

Comment: By default, a user control inherits from the UserControl class provided by the system. The UserControl class provides functionality required by all user controls, and implements standard methods and properties.

Comment: there are also other things to inherit from in NET than finished controls.  e.g. there is a TextBoxBase and a ScrollableControl.  Alas BackgroundImage is already in ScrollableControl,a nd I suspect there is a lot to get it to the Panel level of functionality.

Comment: This is what I have explained, hide them using browser state...

Comment: @Plutonix has mentioned this as well, that's probably why he didn't add an answer either ;)

Comment: If this was just a straight up Class, not a UserControl, then yes, I can inherit from all of those objects.  Project > Add UserControl ... vs ... Project > Add Class .   Not sure why it has different meanings since it is clearly labeled in the IDE, and I have been using the correct terminology for it based off that pretense. See > http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102300/is-there-any-difference-between-custom-control-and-user-control-in-net

Comment: @Plutonix - Thank you for the good descriptions on the other bases. I have already been working with Inherits ScrollableControl (my fave), among others in my custom classes.  The UserControl is mainly to wrap things up into something more presentable, with more control over the exposure of the custom classes involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inherit the Control class if you want to implement a control.  Sure, it has a lot of properties, a .NET control has a wholeheckofalot more functionality than a VB6 Control.  Nothing to panic about, if you want to *hide* a property then you use an attribute:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyControl
    Inherits ScrollableControl

    <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _
    Public Overrides Property BackgroundImage As Image
        Get
            Return MyBase.BackgroundImage
        End Get
        Set
            MyBase.BackgroundImage = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

If you want to enforce it so the client programmer can't cheat then you override the PaintBackground() method as well:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(pevent As PaintEventArgs)
    pevent.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)
End Sub
```

Comment: Base class 'System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl' specified for class 'Board' cannot be different from the base class 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' of one of its other partial types. Using the code above on a UserControl

Comment: Well, if you want to derive from UserControl then use that as the base class.  Obvious, isn't it?

Comment: <Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(False)> _    ...  worked tho.  Just can't extend the control, but that wasn't my question.   Thank you.   Not so obvious as to what to derive from "UserControl" ... since it is assumed that was the base of all controls, however the fact it disallows any derivatives of it, show otherwise :)

Comment: That's sad... just saying.

Comment: Ah, we have somebody in the house with a better answer.  Hmm, too bad he won't share it with us...

Comment: I told him in comments, evidently it wasn't enough... this didn't need an answer, but exactly entails what you added as an answer.

Comment: @Plutonix has mentioned this as well, that's probably why he didn't add an answer either ;)

Comment: @HansPassant great answer though!

Comment: @Mr CoDeXer -- actually, this did need an example since the documentation on how to add those parameters are for C# only, using [], and any use of online tools to convert that code to VB.NET resulted in errors.  The fact that Hans provided an example of how to use those parameters in VB.NET is why I flagged this answer as accepted.  While it does not truly hide (nor does it delve into Shadows for certain properties), the line I am focusing on is "<Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)> _".. Please feel free to check online for yourself. No doc examples.